# Predicate function in VB

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a predicate in C# I am trying to translate into VB.net:

```
user.first_name = claimsIdentity.Claims.First(c => c.Type == System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value;
```

To:

```
user.first_name = claimsIdentity.Claims.First(Function(claim) claim.Type = ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value
```

I am getting the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no matching
>   element'

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this working?

Comment: @Servy Why do you think that this question has nothing to do with C#? The OP clearly mentioned that *I have a predicate in C#* and he is showing his C# code. I think this question could be also tagged as C#!

Comment: @S.Akbari The question *doesn't* have anything to do with C#.  They're asking how to fix a VB function, so that it works in VB.  They're not looking for C# programmers, they're looking for VB programmers.  The fact that the question contains the word C# doesn't mean it's a C# question, or is appropriate for a C# audience.

Comment: @Servy I think he is tagged C# because his main question is why the same code works in C# but will throw *Sequence contains no matching element'* in VB.

Comment: I would thing the person who can provide the correct response would need to understand the C# code to know what needs to be done in the revised vb code.  Just knowing either C# or VB would not necessarily be helpful.  That is why I added both tags

Comment: @jason That's just it the, C# code is entirely irrelevant.  You have some VB code, and an error telling you exactly what the problem is.  That you got to where you are by translating some C# code doesn't really matter, the problem is the same, and the VB code is all you need to look at to fix that error.  Think of it this way, if you never had a C# program and wrote that VB code from scratch, and had the same problem, would the answer be any different?

Comment: Use the `Return` keyword to ensure that the VB.NET compiler knows that you meant to use an expression instead of an assignment.

Comment: @HansPassant The only way I would expect an assignment to compile is if `claim.Type` is a boolean (which it doesn't look like, given the name, although I supposed it's possible).  If it's not a boolean then the code wouldn't compile if it interpreted it as an assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) instead and [Null-conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) operator:

```
user.first_name = claimsIdentity.Claims
  .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimTypes.GivenName)?.Value;
```

It will return *a default value if the sequence contains no elements*.

Comment: Also probably want to use `?.Value` since a null is expected.

Comment: @aquinas Agree. I have included your suggest,

Comment: Also might want to write the lambda in the VB.NET syntax.

Comment: @S.Akbari Hello and thanks for the response.  To be clear, the C# syntax works.  It is the VB syntax I am asking for help on.

Comment: @jason You mean that you have tried the `FirstOrDefault` in VB.NET and it didn't work?

Comment: @S.Akbari I mean, the C# code I posted works as it is.  I have tested it in another application, that is in C#.  I am trying to translate that application to VB.  So, the C# definitely works, as it is posted.  The value will never be null, so therefor will never need a default value.  Of course, using the FirstOrDefault shouldn't hurt.  I just need to translate what is already working, in C#, to VB

Comment: @jason You're not getting an error that the sequence is null, you're getting an error that the sequence is empty. That's different.  We know that your sequence *is* empty (aftering the filtering), because you're getting an error saying so.  If it had at least one value (matching the criteria) you wouldn't have gotten the error.

Comment: @jason As you said *using the `FirstOrDefault` shouldn't hurt* so don't bother yourself and use it and certainly it works. If you don't like the default value of .net you can also use `DefaultIfEmpty` method and define yours.

Comment: @S.Akbar  Thanks for your response.  But,  I think there is some confusion here.  the code you posted is not in VB, which is what I am looking for.  I already know how to do this in C# and it already works.  Now, I just need to translate it to VB.  Or, are you saying that the VB code I posted should work the way it is?

Comment: @jason forget my code. Just replace your `First` with `FirstOrDefault` in your VB.NET. The `FirstOrDefault` is also exists in VB.NET.

Comment: @jason, your VB.NET code is semantically identical to your C# code. If it "works" in C#, that means that the ClaimsIdentity in your C# program has that Claim, but in your VB.NET program it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  There must be something else that was not properly translated.  I am trying to translate a Single Sign On App.  Maybe when it authenticates, it fails without error, hence no claim to search on?